# Не понимаю, что делаю не так с DomPdf

Tags: laravel, dompdf

Пытаюсь отправить сконвертированную view через почту, получаю ошибку Invalid view. Информации, что может быть не так, я не нашёл, подскажите пожалуйста

````
public function build()
    {
        return Pdf::loadView('theme_base.emails.commercial_offer', [
            'commercialOffer' => $this->commercialOffer,
        ])->stream();
    }
    ```
````

Comment: структуру view покажите

Comment: Я уже смог отправить pdf, но вёрстка сильно поехала и как буд-то её нет. Пытался поразному стили добавлять, но ничего не помогло, а стили супер простые, и что-то импортировась, а что-то нет, дайте пожалуйста совет, что можно сделать, чтобы было как в браузере, закидывать html в онлайн конвертер, всё отлично сконвертировало

Comment: @Sararun сам недавно столкнулся. DomPdf не умеет в современную вёрстку, не получится использовать флексбоксы или подобное. Должны быть только div, table и все им присущее и инлайновые стили, то есть в у самих тегов, ещё момент, когда выводишь текст болдом, так и пиши, числа не сработают. И узнай сколько размером страница, прежде чем ее выводить

Answer (score 0):

Всё оказалось куда неприятнее. В итоге всё закончилось тем, что я посадил фронтендера за свой комп, потомучто я в душе не чаю все тонкости старого html. На самом деле, всем советую так делать или менять тестовый сервак для залива